# Short story collection inspired by 50s drive in horror movies

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a book of short stories I read in 1998. I can't swear it was written in the 90s, but that seems right. It was sci fi-horror and was inspired by drive-in B movies. I'm pretty sure the cover had an illustration of a drive-in screen on it. Unfortunately I can't remember a single plot point of any of the stories. Help?

Answer (score 9):

[*It Came From the Drive-in*](http://www.normanpartridge.com/ICFDI.htm) (1996) Edited by Norman Partridge and Martin H. Greenberg

If it is a themed anthology of that era, [Martin H. Greenberg](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?509) is the go-to guy.

Comment: I had never seen this, but I need to find it now. Big Rex Miller fan since "Chaingang".